# "Pixelating" the character 英

Tags: characters, handwriting, calligraphy, character-components

I would like to include a Chinese character (英) in a knitting pattern. To do so, I need to "pixelate" the character.

[image: pixelated 英]

Is this an acceptable representation of the character and is it easily recogniazable, or is there some serious issue with the proportions and readability?

(To clarify, I cannot read/write Chinese.)

Comment: Is this, by chance,  AC:NH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Your original design is good enough as a 'pattern '. And recognizable as 英

My edition just make it closer to a 'character' , and more readable

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an acceptable representation of the character and is it easily
>   recogniazable, or is there some serious issue with the proportions and
>   readability?

I think it can be better if bottom right stroke(bottom right of 央 part) separate from main structure. And there is a little distance between the "+ +" part.